# passing an array of pointers of struct as a ref in C

Tags: c, pointers, reference, struct

I would like to do something like:

```
struct mystruct {
   char *info;
};

// here is where I'm not sure how to
void do_something(struct mystruct **struc){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       *struc[i] = (struct mystruct *) malloc (sizeof (struct mystruct));
       *struc[i]->info = "foo";
    } 
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    struct mystruct **struc;

    struc = (struct mystruct **struc) malloc (sizeof(struct mystruct *struc) * 10);

    dosomething(&struc);
    // do something with struc and its new inserted values
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure how to pass it as a reference so I can make use of it after `dosomething()`

Thanks

Comment: That shouldn't compile. You're passing a `struct mystruct ***` into a function that takes a `struct mystruct **`. That aside, what's the problem? All the values should be accessible to you after the function returns.

Comment: @EboMike: you are right, is not compiling, and that's my question, I guess I'm getting confused on how to handle properly the *, ***.

Comment: `void do_something(struct mystruct **struc)` should take `***struc` as its argument, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is my corrected version. Specifically...

Line 26: no reason to cast the result of `malloc(3)`, it already returns a `void *`

Line 28: don't make a pointless triple-indirect pointer by passing &struc, you have already allocated space for it so it's hard to imagine any possible reason to change it. You want ultimately to pass the exact return value from `malloc(3)` down to the next layer.

Line 11: another unnecessary cast, and we really do want to change the row pointer at `struct[i]`, i.e., `*struc[i]` would change what one of those 10 pointers that `main()` allocated points to, but they haven't been set yet. That's the job here.

And with those changes it works pretty well...

```
 1  #include <stdio.h>
 2  #include <stdlib.h>
 3  
 4  struct mystruct {
 5    char *info;
 6  };
 7  
 8  void do_something(struct mystruct ** struc) {
 9    int i;
10    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
11      struc[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct));
12      struc[i]->info = "foo";
13    }
14  }
15  
16  void do_something_else(struct mystruct ** s) {
17    int i;
18  
19    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
20      printf("%2d: %s\n", i, s[i]->info);
21  }
22  
23  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
24    struct mystruct **struc;
25  
26    struc = malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct *) * 10);
27  
28    do_something(struc);
29    do_something_else(struc);
30    return 0;
31  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `dosomething(&struc);`, use `dosomething(struc);`. You have a `struct mystruct **`, and that's what the function expects.

Instead of

`*struc[i] = (struct mystruct *) malloc (sizeof (struct mystruct));`

Use

`struc[i] = (struct mystruct *) malloc (sizeof (struct mystruct));`

`struc` is a `struct mystruct **`, so `struc[i]` will expect a `struct mystruct *`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider not casting malloc since it is void *:

```
http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1047673478&id=1043284351
```